# Prevent Child Accounts

Tags: record-type, validation-rule

I'm trying to determine how to create a validation rule to prevent child accounts being creating on Accounts with an Account Record Type of Vendor. Not sure if the validation rule should restrict from the child account perspective or from the Vendor account perspective.

```
AND(
 RecordTypeId = Vendor )

)
```

Comment: I'm assuming you would prevent a vendor account being apart of the parent account pick list?

Comment: you can check if selected lookup field (to Account) if it is not null and selected record type is vendor then throw error..

Answer (score 0):

You can use like this:

```
AND(RecordTypeId = Vendor,  
    NOT(ISNULL(ParentId)))
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Really what you're saying is that if the parent Account of the current Account has the 'Vendor' record type, display an error.

It should be as simple as using the following validation rule:

```
Parent.RecordType.DeveloperName = 'Vendor'
```

Where the 'Vendor' is the DeveloperName of the record type.  Usually it's the same as the label, but spaces are replaced by underscores.

This however won't be assesed when you change the record type of a parent account to 'Vendor'.  No errors will be shown informing the user that there are child accounts that shouldn't exist.